# Eclipse does not show java folder in src folder (gradle)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I've cloned gradle project from github and imported it into IDE Spring Tool Suite (eclipse). You see that project calls projectWithGitIgnoreGradle the first item in structure is src/main/java which has default package

[image]

I'm not sure that this is good way, but I created my classes and packages in another project in this src folder:

[image]

but in my case (as you saw in first image) structure in the first src folder has java folder. but in second src folder (image 2) it is empty. And even if I try to create a package or class in second src folder, it doesn't appear in this src folder (but appear in first one).

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? Why classes I create doesn't appear in second src folder? Why here is two different src items in the project?

Comment: The composite source folder `src/main/java` is a shortcut and saves you having to expand `src` and `main` to go to `src/main/java`. In rare cases, the folders `src` and its subfoder `main` are required, which is why they are displayed separately below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first src folder i.e. `src/main/java` consists of all java files whereas, the second *src* folder can contain html, jsp type files and resources such as Images. 
Do have a look on the following image where the first src folder consists of java files and the second one consists of all the view or web files like html, jsp files as well as image folder which consists of images used for your project.

[image]